# three column web design with fixed width sides

Tags: html, css

I want 3 columns: side columns 80px width, center column the rest

my first approach: on page load I calculate screen width, minus 160px and I assign this result to the width of the center column

can this be done in automatic way with css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 2 floated 80px wide columns and left/right margins on the middle one :

```css
div {
  height: 150px; /* <-- fake height */
}
.col {
  background: teal;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}
.center {
  margin: 0 85px; /* <-- width of left/right columns + gutters */
  background: gold;
}
.col.r {
  float: right;
```

```html
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col r"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `float: left;` and `float: right;` for the sides and `overflow:hidden;` for the middle. The width of the middle collumn will automaticly be calculated.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
    <div class="main">
    </div>
</div>
```

-

```
.wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    background: #ff0000;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}


.main {
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/rm8mfcxb/1/

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wqpqsytj/)

html

```
<div id="header">
     <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div id="main-sidebar">
        <p>Text text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="main-content">
        <p>text text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="secondary-sidebar">
        <p>text text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font: 15px/2 Georgia, serif;
    background: #999;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
h1 {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
#page-wrap {
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 560px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;
}
#header {
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 560px;
    background: #222;
    margin: auto 0;
}
#main-content {
    padding: 0 100px;
    background: white;
    min-height:150px;
}
#main-sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 80px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 0 10px;
    min-height:150px;
}
#secondary-sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 80px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 0 10px;
    min-height:150px;
}
#footer {
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 560px;
    background: #222;
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
}
#footer p {
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to dynamically check for anything.

Set the `<table>` width to 100% and the 'side' `<td>`s

```
table{
    width: 100%;
}
.side{
    width: 80px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ecdtaqLo/

Comment: Oh ok.. My bad.. assumed tables from 'columns'